# How can I call a function at time of closing of JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, backup, dispose

As i want to go for backup before the closing of program.
How i can call backup function when user click on (Right corner button of closing that JFrame) button closing over a JFrame? and after back i wants to be frame get disposed system get exited.
 I have setted default closing Operation `setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simply by doing the following:

1. Setting the default close operation to:

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`

2. Adding a new `WindowAdapter` to your frame and override (hooking) on its `windowClosing` method like so:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
        //your logic here
    }
});
```

Also don't forget that you will need to manually dispose the frame as well as call `System#exit` once done in order to close the application.

For more check the related documentation here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html